# Pdf2htmlEx: The html contains images, how could i have instead graphics as output instead of images?

Tags: pdf2htmlex

I have tried every command found in the documentation, how could i get only the text part as output, and not at all the images?

https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Command-Line-Options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve as the question subject and details appears contradictory, but there are options to split out the graphics and text into separate files:

```
--embed <string>
   --embed-css <0|1> (Default: 1)
   --embed-font <0|1> (Default: 1)
   --embed-image <0|1> (Default: 1)
   --embed-javascript <0|1> (Default: 1)
   --embed-outline <0|1> (Default: 1)
          Specify which elements should be embedded into the  output  HTML
          file.

          If  switched  off,  separated files will be generated along with
          the HTML file for the corresponding elements.

          --embed accepts a string as argument. Each letter of the  string
          must  be  one  of  `cCfFiIjJoO`, which corresponds to one of the
          --embed-*** switches. Lower case letters for 0  and  upper  case
          letters  for  1.  For  example,  `--embed  cFIJo` means to embed
          everything but CSS files and outlines.

   --split-pages <0|1> (Default: 0)
          If turned on, the content of each page is stored in a  separated
          file.

          This  switch is useful if you want pages to be loaded separately
          & dynamically -- a supporting server might be necessary.

          Also see --page-filename.
```

So if you use the `--split-pages 1` and `--embed-image 0` options, then you have one HTML page per PDF page, which does not include embedded images.

If this isn't what you want then please include additional information in your question.